# Dynamically set custom AlertDialog content

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom dialog that I set up as a function:

```
public void customDialog(Bitmap bm, String title){
    TextView dialogtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.layout_root);
    //For above also tried r.id.popup which is the containing file for the layout
    ImageView dialogimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.popupimage); 

    dialogtext.setText(title);
    dialogimage.setImageBitmap(bm);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.show();
}
```

The dialog fails whenever I try to set the XML fields dynamically with a Null Pointer Exception. I'm stumped, any ideas? Do I have to add something to the manifest for a custom dialog?

Comment: Can you post the XML file with the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this first:

`View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));`

Then, after you define `layout`, do this:

`ImageView dialogimage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupimage);`

Call `findViewByID()` on the new layout you created, not on the parent content view.

So two changes:  Ordering, and `layout.findView` not `findView`

Comment: what is layout_root. Please help